# I installed Ubuntu on an external UDS HDD. My boot disappeared. Why?

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, usb, hard-drive

I can't explain why my boot disappeared, after I did it:

1. I plug a pendrive (live Linux Debian) + a virgin HDD-USB, all that on my linux Debian Machine.

**[usb pendrive live Linux] <=plugged=> My Linux PC <==plugged==> [virgin HDD-USB]**

2. I boot on the live USB pendrive
3. From it, I install Linux on the HDD-USB virgin drive... Ok all good. Install success !
4. **I unplug everybody, I reboot: OUCH, my machine displays a *blackdeath* grub screen.
   How can this be possible ? What's wrong in my process ?**

What's wrong with that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried this setup for installation but no luck it'll only success after when i remove my primary HDD plug the USB one by removing it from its cover do complete installation and placing back the USB & primary laptop HDD at their original place. Now i am able to boot my USB HDD as external.

As in your condition i suggest Make sure you install grub on your external HD during installation check if that could workout.

Comment: Thanks. Well, you plugged out the non-USB primary HDD before installing on USB-secondary-HDD, right ? Finally I'm reinstalling Linux on the non-USB-rimary-HDD, that's it. Opportunity to pass it LUKS encrypted btw.